# Installing Windows Identity Foundation 3.5 with no Internet?

Tags: wif

Need to get WIF 3.5 installed on a system in a secure environment where there is no Internet access.  The installer you save to disk from the WIF download page will work ONLY if you have an Internet connection.  How/where can I get a full installer for WIF 3.5?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't played with WIF 3.5 for a while but this is the page that I used to use:

[Windows Identity Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=17331)

There are a number of different options, so read the "Install Instructions".

Then download and copy over.